# WxButton - mouse hover & border size

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Currently, I built a Login form by using Wxsmith in code blocks IDE, I would like to know is there a way that I can add the mouse hover effect to Wxbutton and change border-radius?

I went through https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_any_button.html

there is something called "void wxAnyButton::SetBitmapCurrent(const wxBitmap & bitmap)" for mouse hover. But can't understand it really and I don't know where to use it. please help me new to Wxwidgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed change the bitmap shown by the button by calling `SetBitmapCurrent()` function and passing it the bitmap you want to use in the "hover" state. If you do this, you may want to also use a bitmap for the button in the normal state using `SetBitmapLabel()`.

There is no way to change border radius of the native button directly because it simply doesn't use any such thing.

Comment: Ok, I did it like this please correct me if I'm wrong.

1. I include this -> #include <wx/anybutton.h> in top of my mian.cpp
2. then I added these two functions in mian.cpp
            ->wxAnyButton::GetBitmapCurrent()const{}
            ->wxAnyButton::SetBitmapCurrent(const wxBitmap& bitmap){}
but it gives me errors

Comment: What do you mean "added these two functions"? You don't need to add them, just call them. Also, no need to include `wx/anybutton.h`, `wx/button.h` already includes it (it's harmless if you do it too, but perfectly useless).